# how to present negative value with log scaling in paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview

I am trying to display the physical quantity of each vertex in the mesh by paraview.
The ranges of the physical quantity ranges from positive to negative.
I want to display both positive and negative values in log scale in paraview in the same way as proposed by [Alan in 2014](https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2014-July/031544.html). 
That is

> I propose that we find maxVal = max(maximum, abs(minimum)).  Then, we set the color bar to run from maxVal to -maxVal.  We log scale the top half of the color legend, running from maxVal to maxVal*10^-4, and we reverse log scale the bottom half of the color legend, running from -maxVal*10^-4 to -maxVal.

(As he said -4 is an arbitrary parameter.)

One question is that
I think this proposal has not implemented in paraview(I use version 5.2),
is it right?

And another question is that is there a way to draw colors as Alan proposed in paraview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has not been implemented as of ParaView 5.4, and it is currently not possible to achieve that coloring.